# Laravel get value from my function in Model

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

My model Dispatch has a field invoice_id.
It is a foreign key so i can get the invoice details using the below code:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'truck_no',      
    'driver_name',      
    'driver_phone',      
    'gps_details',      
    'invoice_id',      
];

public function invoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice')->select('id','invoice_no','permit_id');
}
```

Now I want to get the value permit_id from invoice() so i can use it to get the details of the Permit.

**permit_id = id of Permit model**

So I use the below code to get the permit data.

```
public function permit(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Permit','id',$this->invoice()->permit_id);
}
```

Update:

My Invoice Model has :

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'invoice_no',
        'invoice_date',
        'permit_id',
    ];

    public function permit(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Permit', 'id', 'permit_id');
    }
}
```

My Permit Model has:

```
class Permit extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'permit_type',
        'permit_no',
        'application_no',  
        'supply_unit', 
        'supply_unit_id' ,  
     ];

    public function supplyunit(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\SupplyUnit','id','supply_unit_id');
    }
}
```

And as per suggestions i have added below code in my Dispatch Model:

```
 class Dispatch extends Model
  {
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'truck_no',      
        'driver_name',      
        'driver_phone',      
        'gps_details',      
        'invoice_id',      
    ];

    public function invoice(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice','id','invoice_id');
    }

    public function permit(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Permit','id','permit_id');
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. What should i do to achieve the above? Is there any other solutions please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each invoice has one permit, your relationship definition should look like this:

```
public function permit(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Permit', 'id', 'permit_id');
}
```

Edit: If invoice belongs to permit, which is the inverse, your relationship would look like this instead:

```
public function permit(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Permit', 'permit_id');
}
```

Edit: Based on your updated question, I think you got the relationship definitions a bit wrong. The following should work:

Since you have an `invoice_id` column in `App\Dispatch`, it means that each `App\Dispatch` belongs to an invoice.

In `App\Dispatch`, your relationship definition should be as follows:

```
public function invoice() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}

// permit does not belong to `App\Dispatch` as a direct relationship
// it should be removed
```

In `App\Invoice`, your relationship definition should be as follows:

```
public function dispatch() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Dispatch');
}

public function permit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Permit');
}
```

In `App\Permit`, your relationship definition should be as follows:

```
public function invoice() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
}
```

To then retrieve the permit id from an Invoice model, you would do

```
$invoice->permit->id;
```

Comment: Yes each invoice belongs to one permit.

          public function permit(){
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Permit');
          }
This is what i use. 
But your code shows null.

Comment: Edited my answer to define the inverse of the relationship.

Comment: Can you show us your relationship definitions in the following classes: `App\Permit`, `App\Dispatch` and `App\Invoice`?

Comment: Ok should we start a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186616/discussion-between-lano-angel-and-mozammil).

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Ohk but what should i do to get permit details in Dispatch model? I could use another filed to store permit_id in dispatch model, but i want to get the details using the invoice(). Is it possible?

Comment: Permit has one invoice which has one dispatch. So, to get your permit details from a dispatch instance you would do `App\Dispatch::find(1)->invoice->permit` (for example)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice')->select('id','invoice_no','permit_id');
```

To

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
```

And add the following code on Invoice

```
public function permit(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Permit');
}
```

And you can access as

```
Dispatch::find($id)->invoice->permit->id;
```

Or if you want all the information

```
Dispatch::find($id)->invoice->permit;
```

Comment: check this. you can easily get all the information.

Comment: I want to get it in the model itself. Using the invoice().Is it possible?

Comment: don't know about that since i didn't need to do that. but what are you hoping to gain from that?

Comment: The reason is because i would have to loop through all the data and add permit_no like this.



`$dispatches = Dispatch::with('invoice')->get(); 
        foreach ($dispatches as $index => $value) {
            $permit_no = Dispatch::find($value->id)->invoice->permit->permit_no;
            $value['sno'] = ++$index;
            $value['permit_no'] = $permit_no;
        } `

Comment: you can do this way.`$dispatches= Dispatch::all(); foreach($dispatches as $dispatch){ $permit_no = $dispatch->invoice->permit->id; }`. Likewise you can get others as well. Don't need to call the model again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186618/discussion-between-yasiru-sellahewa-and-lano-angel).